# Why do I experience extreme lag but my friend does not in Minecraft FTB?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, performance

I've been trying to play Minecraft: Feed the Beast with my friend. We decided to download the Mindcrack pack. The server is installed on my friends computer, and I downloaded the client and hamachi to connect. My friend can play fine, but I get extreme lag.

I can destroy blocks, but the items hop into my inventory after about half a minute later.

We're using skype too, and note that when playing Vanilla Minecraft we are able to play smoothly.

Any ideas why I can't play properly?

Comment: FTB tends to cause some lag. It is the nature of the beast. The lag you're describing is likely caused by a combination of a slight connection issue and the intrinsic tick lag that FTB tends to cause. I doubt it's a memory issue if you're friend is fine.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Thanks! 2GB did the job. Post your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### MOAR RAM

On a slightly more serious note, **kill Skype**. It's using precious resources. **Get rid of Hamachi** and learn how to port forward. The more things running at the same time, the more lag you're going to experience. Get OptiFine, but turn off all the stuff you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce lag on the client side (where I think your lag is), you should set render distance to Normal (or shorter if you have an older computer), set graphics to fast, disable clouds, turn off smooth lighting, set performance to balanced, turn off particles, and, if you have a newer computer, turn ON Advanced OpenGL. If this issue persists, you can grab [OptiFine](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-) (use the light version if you just want an FPS increase, otherwise go ultra) and then open FTB, then click Edit Mod Pack > Coremods > Add Mod and add the file you downloaded. Hope this helps!

Comment: FWIW, OptiFine actually slowed my FTB install down. Make sure you disable all the graphics improvements OptiFine adds if you're just looking for FPS.

Comment: Right, I forgot about the extra stuff it adds. It also adds a few menus to switch specific things to fast. If you just want FPS, use the light version of OptiFine.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce lag minimise render distance and change option to Max FPS.

Comment: This really isn't much of an answer. Please try elaborating on why these things may affect the lag.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have enough storage. If you do not, you can use apps to free up space from your photos. I would use microsoft onedrive. All you need is space for an open app and a microsoft account. It will upload to your microsoft account. This will free up space. Or to increase your storage make sure you are using a device that has an sd card slot and get an sd card. I dont know how you will fix this if either dont work, because if they dont, just read another answer.

Answer (score -3):

I know why youre lagging I lag a lot on tekkit a lot more on tekkit lite and extreme on FTB why try to get a better modpack with good mods but without A lot of mods Like Voltz and tekkit classic Voltz have like 20 mods And tekkit lite has like 48 mods I play on small render fas graphics no cluds and max fps I this halped nothing or a bit try downloading optifine

Comment: Saying "don't use that modpack use my favourite instead" is not a useful answer to the question of *why* there is extreme lag on one machine but not the other.

Comment: You say that you know the reason, but then go on a rant about "better modpacks". Could you provide an actual reason why the OP's game is lagging and provide why you think the mods you are advocating in it's stead are better?