# Extreme Block Lag on Minecraft Feed the Beast

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have a pretty good gaming computer and I am having trouble playing Feed the Beast. This problem has happened pretty recently. The change wasn't sudden but it deteriorated very quickly.

I am on a single player world and there is block lag. I cannot pick up items on the ground, I have trouble breaking blocks, and when I right-click on machines it takes 2-3 seconds before I see the interface.  Machines take way longer than they are supposed to.

My FPS is stable at 120 and the game is smooth, but sometimes I teleport back to where I was 5 seconds ago. The world I play on is pretty small. None of these problems affect me on regular Minecraft or on other FTB worlds I have created. I am currently running the mindcrack pack. I have tried installing Optifine but it doesn't help. I don't have any windows or programs open when I play.

I have 64 bit Java and am using 4 out of 8GB RAM to run the game. I have tried reinstalling the game and think that the problem is with the actual world.

Comment: For clarification this is a "blockLag" problem not a FPS problem

Comment: There are a couple million things that could be causing this. Are you noticing anything weird in the console and are there any machines in particular this happens with? The fact that it only happens in one world leads me to believe that it's not a RAM issue or anything of that nature, but rather, related to something in the world. Or perhaps the switch from Rei's caused some weirdness.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ 4 GB should be more than enough.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/111753/ftb-mindcrack-pack-cant-play-properly-extreme-lag

Comment: Do you have any complex redstone circuits or constantly-running complex machines, or lots of items moving around all the time? The problem is almost certainly your world, but you haven't told us anything about it. Are you in the habit of moving through multiple Ages a lot?

Comment: Thx for the advice.  I dont have any complex red stone circuts. However I do have a quarry hooked up ender chest with a pheumatic tube/barrel sorting system.  As well i had one redstone timer, one wireless transmitter, and four wireless recevers but i have already removed them and the bad block lag still countinues no machines are constantly in use. I dont think that the "Ages" mod is in the mindcrack pack.  As far as ive seen from other peoples worlds youtube there is nothing in my world that would cause this amount of lag

Comment: i removed all the chunk loaders and went 700 blocks away and still it was very difficult to break blocks.  All my solar panels are sending power to my mfsus as far as i know and there are no loops.  Do you think the lag will be fixed next time they update the pack?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft.

Answer (score 6):

A ton of the mods in FTB are very poorly coded *(eg. to check if solar-panels can see sun, they use the dumbest algorithm possible:  a `for` loop that checks every y-value above it for blocks **every freakin' server tick**)*.

To test if this is your issue, remove all [world anchors](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/World_Anchor) *(and all similar blocks that keep chunks loaded)* and go far away from your main-base to someplace you've never been *(so that everything you've built becomes unloaded)*.  If the "lag" stops, then the problem is most likely a CPU-hungry mod.

There's not much you can do about CPU-hungry mods except [turn them off](http://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/disabling-mods.1556/), or *(in single-player only)* just promise yourself not to use blocks from the laggy-mods.  Because it's a CPU-issue, reducing the graphics won't help.  You could try [increasing the process priority](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Process-Priorities-in-Windows-Task-Manager), but that likely won't help much, and could cause stability problems.

Unfortunately, there's no ultimate-list of laggy mods that I know of, and the list changes with every version anyways.  [Check the FTB forums](http://forum.feed-the-beast.com/forums/server-admin-area.41/), and see which mods most server-administrators are currently disabling, and why.

Comment: I know there was something about advanced solar panels complaining in the logs 32 times per tick if they don't have a place to send power, or something stupid like that too. There's all kinds of things like that...

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try reducing video quality along with other things that help kill CPU.. i.e. render dist, fancy graphics, lighting. Its always better to go for 'function over form' settings.

Answer (score -1):

You should **wait** and let your world load then *Block Lag* will be reduced